# Array variable in command in url

Tags: bash

I have problem with url formatting in bash script. In below code url request:

```
text="$(lynx --dump https://address/"${array[${i}]}")"
```

returns **HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid**. I assume that on

```
"${array[${i}]}"
```

is something wrong in url part. But I can't figure out what is right format.

```
#!/bin/bash

saveIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(<words))
IFS="$saveIFS"

elements=${#array[@]}

for (( i=0;i<$elements;i++))
do
    text="$(lynx --dump https://address/"${array[${i}]}")"

    echo "$text" >> "outputfilename"
fi
done
```

I also tried:

```
text="$(lynx --dump https://address/${array[${i}]})"
```

Comment: Instead of calling `lynx`, try `text="$(echo https://address/${array[${i}]})"`, then you may get a better clue what is going on.

Comment: 1) If some line contains glob characters, it will be expanded. Use `readarray` to read lines of a file to an array instead. 2) You don't need to store the lines at all. Just loop over them: [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I was reading windows file.** Lines ended with CR LF. So address contains

```
\r
```

character. I can remove it:

```
array[${i}]=${array[${i}]%$'\r'}
```

**Or I can reformat input file so lines end only with LF.**

Main structure of working script reading from CR LF file is

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a array <words
elements=${#array[@]}

for (( i=0;i<$elements;i++))
do
   array[${i}]=${array[${i}]%$'\r'}
   text="$(lynx --dump https://adrress/"${array[${i}]}")"

if [ ${#text} -gt 1 ]
then
    echo "$text" >> "filename"
else
    echo "${array[${i}]}" >> "filename2"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

### Try

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' read -rd '' -a array <words
elements=${#array[@]}

for (( i=0;i<$elements;i++))
do
    text="$(lynx --dump https://address/"${array[${i}]}")"
    echo "$text" >> "outputfilename"
done
```

- The array variable wasn't being set with `array=($(<words))`
- You can use `read` or `readarray`, but this example is with `read`

Incidentally, putting `IFS=$'\n'` before `read` without a command separator `;` sets `$IFS` only for the read command, removing the need to save and re-set `$IFS`

Comment: U could write `${array[i]}` instead of `${array[${i}]}`!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array at all; the following will work in any POSIX-compatible shell, assuming you have one URL component per line:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  text=$(lynx --dump https://address/"$line")
  echo "$text"
done < words >> output filename
```

Comment: Correct, `printf -v` work only under [tag:bash]. Anyway, I like using them. +1 for *correct* way of using STDIO, ( but `text="$()"...echo "$text"` is useless! Yoiu could whipe this and only use `lynx -dump "$url"` ;)

Comment: it ensures there is a newline after the text, so no, not entirely useless.

Answer (score 1):

## My two cents...

I prefer use `printf -v` for this, and this could be build like a *filter*:

```
catWeb() {
    while IFS= read -r word;do
        printf -v url "https://address/%s" "$word"
        lynx --dump "$url"
    done
}
catWeb <words >outputfilename
```